# How do i format text before writing to a text file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a script that retrieves information from a database and I need to write out the results to file.  During the retrieve process I pull the column headers and data which I like to show in a neat format.  Here is an example of what I need it to look like:

```
user_name             name                          num_logins   
email_1@yahoo.com     Beachwood                     2            
email_2@yahoo.com     Beachwood                     2             
email_3@yahoo.com     Beachwood                     2             
email_4@yahoo.com     Beachwood                     2             
email_55@yahoo.com    Community Internal Medicine   6
```

I am new at creating a report/file in a specific format so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the output to be fixed width or just delimited appropriately?  What's the use case for the output?

Comment: Yes.  I am looking for it to be fixed with.

Answer (score 2):

The [Hirb](https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb) gem can be a good starting point for you. It's usually associated with IRB or Rail's console use, but there's nothing that says we can't subvert it for other uses.

Normally it wants to wrap the table created with ASCII borders:

```
+--------------------+-----------------------------+------------+
| user_name          | name                        | num_logins |
+--------------------+-----------------------------+------------+
| email_1@yahoo.com  | Beachwood                   | 2          |
| email_2@yahoo.com  | Beachwood                   | 2          |
| email_3@yahoo.com  | Beachwood                   | 2          |
| email_4@yahoo.com  | Beachwood                   | 2          |
| email_55@yahoo.com | Community Internal Medicine | 6          |
+--------------------+-----------------------------+------------+
```

But, by applying a bit of `gsub` lovin' we can dress it up like you want:

```
values = [
  [ 'user_name',          'name',      'num_logins'          ],
  [ 'email_1@yahoo.com',  'Beachwood', '2'                   ],
  [ 'email_2@yahoo.com',  'Beachwood', '2'                   ],
  [ 'email_3@yahoo.com',  'Beachwood', '2'                   ],
  [ 'email_4@yahoo.com',  'Beachwood', '2'                   ],
  [ 'email_55@yahoo.com', 'Community Internal Medicine', '6' ],
]
puts Hirb::Helpers::AutoTable.render(
  values,
  :headers => values.shift,
  :description => false
).gsub(/^[+-]+\n?/, '').gsub('|', ' ')
```

Which looks like:

```
  user_name            name                          num_logins  
  email_1@yahoo.com    Beachwood                     2           
  email_2@yahoo.com    Beachwood                     2           
  email_3@yahoo.com    Beachwood                     2           
  email_4@yahoo.com    Beachwood                     2           
  email_55@yahoo.com   Community Internal Medicine   6
```

You might want to pop off the header line of the array before passing it to Hirb, or supply it from a separate array. Change the `:headers` option if so.

Answer (score 1):

You should look up the ruby `printf` method, which is very similar to the C function by the same name.  It lets you specify field width and alignment for every value you are printing.

```
printf "%20d %20d\n", 334, 44
```

Comment: [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) is my preferred way of doing formatting, as it's a more general-purpose way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, `String#%` is great too.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how fancy you want your tables to be, you might be able to use a gem such as [terminal-table](https://github.com/visionmedia/terminal-table) for this.

The README on Github doesn't mention it, but [this pull request](https://github.com/visionmedia/terminal-table/pull/3.patch) shows how to disable the table's borders.

> ```
> Terminal::Table::X = ""
> Terminal::Table::Y = ""
> Terminal::Table::I = ""
> ```

Comment: Mark, I like terminal-table but I am struggling with creating it dynamically with the data returned from database query.  Each query return will have different number of columns returned.  How can I accomplish this?  array with an array

Comment: @Jfleck [the Tin Man's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14404234/126042) has a basic demonstration of nested arrays.  If you need more specific help, you should start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try my table_print gem - it's very flexible but requires little setup/configuration http://github.com/arches/table_print